# What is a word that means small pieces coming together to make a big thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a word that means small pieces coming together to make a big thing?

I'm looking for a word like "snowballing".

Comment: Coalesce, unite, join together, combine, merge, fuse, mingle, meld, blend, intermingle, knit (together), amalgamate, consolidate, integrate, affiliate, link up, homogenize, synthesize, converge. (Just from one quick Google.)

Comment: coalesce, fleet.

Comment: aggregate would be my choice, but an example sentence would be helpful.

Comment: Can you come up with an example sentence to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The particles/elements **coalesce** (the noun being **coalescence**).

> *coalesce* [verb] (intr) to unite or come together in one body or mass; merge; fuse; blend

{[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coalesce)}

> *coalesce*  v. ...
>
> v.intr.
>
> 1. To come or grow together into a single mass: the material that coalesced to form stars.
> 2. To come together as a recognizable whole or entity: the stories that coalesced as the history of the movement.
> 3. To come together for a single purpose: The rebel units coalesced into one army to fight the invaders. See Synonyms at mix.
>
> v.tr.
>
> 1. To cause to coalesce as a single mass: The atoms were coalesced into a larger molecule.
> 2. To cause to coalesce as a single whole or entity: The survey responses were coalesced into a single document.

{[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/coalesce)}

Answer (score 1):

**accrete**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/accrete)

As in:

> process of accretion

ac·cret·ed, ac·cret·ing, ac·cretes

> To make larger or greater, as by increased growth. To grow together;
>   fuse.  To grow or increase gradually, as by addition.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy...

> the interaction or cooperation of two or more organizations, substances, or other agents to produce a combined effect greater than the sum of their separate effects.
>
> "the synergy between artist and record company"
>
> synonyms: cooperative interaction, cooperation, combined effort, give
>   and take
>
> "there's no synergy between the two, so no costs are saved"